# How to search a series of arrays for a particular match and display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, each

I have a text field that a user types in, this is then used to match what the user types against a set of strings in stored vars.

This is what I have so far:

```
var sports = ['skateboarding','bmx','surfing','longboarding','snowboarding'];
var interests = ['photography', 'editing', 'film making'];
var hobbies = ['gaming', 'music', 'tv'];

$('#test').bind('input change',function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    $.each([sports, interests, hobbies], function(index, value){
        $.each(value, function(key, cell){
            if (search.indexOf(cell) != -1){
                $('ul').append('<li>' + value[key] + '</li>');
            }else{

            }
        });
    });
});
```

As a base this works but only matched the full word, not parts of the word. How would I be able to do this so that any parts of the word are matched. For example:
if the user types board, it would match skateboarding, longboarding and snowboarding.

And is there an easy to remove words that are no longer matches from the ul list.

I have a JS fiddle as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/84GM5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use indexOf on the strings in the array to compare each one, something like this

```
$('#test').on('input', function(){
    var val = this.value,
        res = $.grep([].concat(sports, interests, hobbies), function(value) {
            return value.indexOf(val) != -1;
    });

    res = $.trim(val).length > 0 ? res : []; // account for empty value

    $('ul').html( $.map(res, function(val) {
        return $('<li />', {text: val});
    }));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/84GM5/5/)

Comment: thanks, that a lot better than searching for the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if (search.indexOf(cell) != -1){
```

With:

```
if (cell.indexOf(search) != -1){
```

Then, it searches for the current search string, in the current word.

You'll need to add a `$('ul').empty();` in the `change` event handler, though.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/84GM5/2/)